# Cannot find provider for ActivatedRoute in library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a library with a module that I would like to use the router to get the `queryParams` from using the `ActivatedRoute` service. However, when the page loads I get a DI error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

I am using storybook which sets up the app module like this:

```js
export default {
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        MyModule,
        RouterModule
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Next in the library the module looks like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule // Tried with and without this line
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Then finally I create the component like this:

```js
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    // Cannot find this service
    private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to import the module like `RouterModule.forRoot([])` or `RouterModule.forChild([])`?

Comment: @DanielGuzman yeah I have tried that too